# Effective control entry into the array - JAVA

Tags: java, arrays

i want to ask you, what is better way, how to add item to array if i need check if the index exists(array length is OK)?

1)

```
private void addItemToArray(int[] arr, int index, int item)
{
     if(index >= 0 && index < arr.length) {
          //put item
     }
}
```

2)

```
private void addItemToArray(int[] arr, int index, int item)
{
   try {
       //put item
   catch(Exception e) {
       return;
   }
}
```

Comment: Well, since the first example won't ever work, you can only use the second one ...

Comment: @Tom: sorry only typing error :-)

Comment: A typing error like `arr.lenght`? :)

Comment: Depends on the use case, the try/catch case is fastest only if the index most of the time is valid. But I somewhat question the whole idea of a method which does somply nothing when the precondition is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the if (first method) is better, as catching errors is costly in terms of performance.

Just a note, the if clause is wrong, you want to check

```
if(index > 0 && index < arr.length){
          //put item
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

An exception is definitely a better alternative than doing nothing, since the caller of the method must have a way of knowing that the index they supplied was invalid. Though catching the exception and doing nothing in the catch block, as you did in the second snippet, is pointless.

You can take example from `ArrayList`, which contains an internal array :

```
/**
 * Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this
 * list. Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and
 * any subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices).
 *
 * @param index index at which the specified element is to be inserted
 * @param element element to be inserted
 * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {@inheritDoc}
 */
public void add(int index, E element) {
  if (index > size || index < 0)
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
    "Index: "+index+", Size: "+size);

  ensureCapacity(size+1);  // Increments modCount!!
  System.arraycopy(elementData, index, elementData, index + 1,
         size - index);
  elementData[index] = element;
  size++;
}
```

If you must avoid throwing exceptions, the very least you can do is have the method return a `boolean` that indicates whether the array was modified.